# SQL Doctrine: InnerJoin where A.key = B.key or A.key = NULL

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, query-builder

I'm trying to do a "complex" SQL request using Doctrine:
I've got a sport project with multiple delegations.
I created events ('`e`') to tell each ones what will happen next.

One event can be for multiple delegations, and if it's for all, it's linked to no one (to save database space)
Then I've got a ManyToMany relation beetween Events and Delegations

And I would like to fetch all events that concern one delegation ('A') after now(`->where('e.startTime > :date')`)
This event are linked by an:

```
->innerJoin('e.delegations', 'd', 'WITH', 'd.name = A' )
```

This work quite good, but for event associated with no one delegation it doesn't get returned
then I tried:

```
->leftJoin('e.delegations', 'd', 'WITH', 'd.name = A' )
```

But this return all the events

Then I need to add an `orWhere` to get catch the `e.delegations = null` but I don't know how to use it, because this will break the previous where that was concerning the time.
Or maybe I can specify something in the innerJoin (like a or NULL or something) but I didn't find this in any [Doctrine QueryBuilder Doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)
I found [this](http://www.mon-code.net/article/32/gestion-des-parenthese-avec-le-querybuilder-de-doctrine-2) in french, but this is only a join and selected using a Where, then it's certainly not optimal compare to an inner/left Join, and will be harder to maintain.

Comment: Let's see if I followed you. You want any event `e` with delegation 'A' or without any delegation at all, but in any case with `e.startTime > :date' where `:date` is now.

Comment: Have you wrote the statement in SQL yet? This will help you translate it to DQL or the QueryBuilder. If not you could show the structure of your entities/tables?

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes That's exactly that. And I don't know how can I do that using the QueryBuilder
@Kwido I did'n try to write it in SQL but this could certainly looks like:
`SELECT 
  e0_.id AS id_0, 
FROM 
  events e0_ 
  JOIN events_delegations e3_
  JOIN delegations d2_
WHERE 
  e0_.start_time > NOW() 
  AND ( (e0_.id = e3_.events_id
  AND d2_.id = e3_.delegations_id AND (d2_.name = A) )
      OR e0_.id NOT IN (e3_.events_id) )`
Here I join using WHERE and use NOT IN to get the event that are not associated to any delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

This problem is a little trick because once we filter delegation by name (`d.name = A`), for all purposes any event (`e`) which don't have that delegation, but have others, will be treated as it didn't any. Because the filter will "remove" others delegations to be returned.

**Solution**

Solve this by using a subquery:

```
//subquery - only returns event which has delegation 'A'
$sqb->select('e1.id')
    ->from('MyNamespace\Entity\Event','e1')
    ->innerJoin('e1.delegations', 'd', 'WITH', "d.name = 'A'");

//main query 
$qb
   ->leftJoin('e.delegations', 'd')       
   ->andWhere('e.delegation is null or e.id in ('.$sqb->getDQL().')');
```

**PS**
If you need use a placehold (`:param`) in a subquery, always set the parameter in the main QueryBuilder.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just had to change: `=null` to `IS NULL`. And as `A` is a parameter, it needs to be set on the main query and not in the subQuery (If not I get the error: `Too few parameters`). I hope this could help other people.

Comment: Sure. I will update the answer. Use `setParameter()` always in the main query.